# Show only the 1st line of text in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I reveal the 1st line of text only? If I have something like this:

```
<View> 
  <Text>
    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, 
  </Text>
</View>
```

I only want **"Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum"** to show up.

Comment: Read doc before ask: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the prop `numberOfLines` to restrict the text from overflowing:

```
<Text numberOfLines={1}>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, 
</Text>
```

This will wrap your text when the limit of parent view is reached, like:

```
 Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not...
```

Comment: you don't need to import anything just use it!

Answer (score -1):

You can create a specialise Text component that only render a substring of the assigned value.